# How to use same field value at multiple places in Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I have a requirement for transforming JSON and I am trying to use the same value multiple times. Is there a way to use value multiple times previously I did use in array but this time I have to go through the level. Any help is appreciated and thank you.

Note I want to filter product configurations based on the name.

How to use same field value at multiple places in Jolt

Input:

```json
{
  "sample": {
    "Result": {
      "value": {
        "ImplProductConfigurationsOptionsEcomResponse": {
          "transactionId": "12345678",
          "timeStamp": 1646087177771,
          "orderCorrelationId": "11039714",
          "implValidateMultiProductConfigurationsResponse": {
            "productConfigurations": [
              {
                "productConfiguration": {
                  "productSpecification": {
                    "name": "Private",
                    "id": "247541"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "productConfiguration": {
                  "productSpecification": {
                    "name": " sample Miscellaneous",
                    "id": "22222"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Current output:

```json
{
  "productConfigurations": {
    "productConfiguration": {
      "productSpecification": {
        "name": "Private",
        "id": "247541"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
  "productConfigurations": {
    "productConfiguration": {
      "productSpecification": {
        "name": "Private",
        "id": "247541"
      }
    }
  },
  "Details": {
    "ImplProductConfigurationsOptionsEcomResponse": {
      "transactionId": "12345678",
      "timeStamp": 1646087177771,
      "orderCorrelationId": "11039714",
      "implValidateMultiProductConfigurationsResponse": {
        "productConfigurations": [
          {
            "productConfiguration": {
              "productSpecification": {
                "name": "Private",
                "id": "247541"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "productConfiguration": {
              "productSpecification": {
                "name": " sample Miscellaneous",
                "id": "22222"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "sample": {
        "Result": {
          "value": {
            "ImplProductConfigurationsOptionsEcomResponse": {
              "implValidateMultiProductConfigurationsResponse": {
                "productConfigurations": {
                  "*": {
                    "productConfiguration": {
                      "productSpecification": {
                        "name": {
                          "*Miscellaneous": null,
                          "*": {
                            "@4": "productConfigurations"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the object twice along with a **shift** transformation spec such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": {
              "*": "Details.&1.&",
              "implValidateMultiProductConfigurationsResponse": {
                "*": {
                  "*": {
                    "*": {
                      "*": {
                        "name": {
                          "*Miscellaneous": {
                            "@3": "Details.&8.&7.&6[].&4"
                          },
                          "*": {
                            "@4": "&6",
                            "@3": "Details.&8.&7.&6[].&4"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

[image]

Comment: If we have more than one then its creating an array of objects inside productConfigurations is there a way that we can avoid this

Comment: @Sandy It *must* be array of objects, two successive objects under common key cannot be nested within curly braces but square brackets. eg. `{
  "productConfigurations": {
    {
      "productConfiguration": {
        "productSpecification": {
          "name": "Private",
          "id": "247541"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "productConfiguration": {
        "productSpecification": {
          "name": "Public",
          "id": "247542"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}` is not a valid JSON value